# Use Spring Boot LDAP authentication with Angular 7

Tags: angular, spring-boot, spring-security-ldap

I am working on an application which has two layers: Front End - based on Angular 7, a separate deployable. Back End - Spring Boot, separate deployable.

I have a login form in Angular, and when the user submits username and password, I want to use LDAP to authenticate the user. For the same, I have created a /login resource in spring, however, am not sure how to use LDAP for authentication from here.

Once user will login successfully, spring application will generate a token and that token will then be used with subsequent requests.

I am stuck at the first part, where I need to use LDAP for user authentication. Could anyone please help me with the same?